# TypeScript return object constructed form generic

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define following generic function to process conversion from interface type to class type implementing this interface. Consider following interface/class pair:

```
interface IExample {
  num: number;
}

class Example implements IExample {
  num: number;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to define function that adheres to following contract:

```
function fromInterfaceToObject<I, O extends I>(iIn: I): O
```

So it takes interface object and return class object basing on passed interface. Problem is that I need to use `new` inside this function:

```
function fromInterfaceToObject<I, O extends I>(iIn: I): O{
  return new O(iIn);
}
```

Which generates typescript error:
`O only refers to type, but is being used as a value here`. I made some research by myself end got  following TS cookbook instructions [on referring class types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) but to be honest I'm unable to apply example to my use case... all following definitions fails:

```
function fromInterfaceToObject<I, O extends I>(iIn: I): {new(I): O} 
function fromInterfaceToObject<I, O: {new(): O}>(iIn: I): O
```

I'd be grateful for any support with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `O` does not exist at runtime (generics are erased at runtime in typescript), and at runtime you need to use `O` to instantiate the new class. You need to pass the actual constructor to the function:

```
function fromInterfaceToObject<I, O extends I>(iIn: I, o: new (iIn: I) => O): O {
    return new o(iIn);
}

fromInterfaceToObject({ num: 10 }, Example);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. One question, where can i find some official docs on Typescript interpretation of Class name as equivalent to constructor function?

Comment: @Tomas I'm not sure .. I'm more self taught when it comes to Typescript, basarat has some books on TS, there might be some stuff in there https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat

Comment: Thank you, I'm asking because this concept was a major brake point in my understanding and it's absolutely unusual in programming world. Thank you, with this knowledge I'm able to create generic classes that provides awesome functionality for my and my team.