# TypeScript mapping enum

Tags: typescript

In my application we work on mix of mocks and real REST data. In TypeScript i have whole bunch of enumse defined for convenience.

When I create any kind of mock array with data, I use following constriction:

```
enum MyEnum { 'myEnumValue1' = 0, myEnumValue2 } 
(...)
 enumField: MyEnum.myEnumValue1,
(...)
```

which is effectively resolved by TypeScript to number:

```
(...)
enumField: 1,
(...)
```

However, form my REST API I'm receiving same set of enums as their string representation. Conversion in both way is possible via:

```
MyEnum['string'] => number
MyEnum[number] => string

MyEnum['myEnumValue1'] => 0
MyEnum[0] => 'myEnumValue1'
```

Is it possible to generate generic class that will handle this conversion in graceful way, similar to how Stack Community suggested me in [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529721/typescript-return-object-constructed-form-generic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function similar to the one for objects:

```
// Return type is a bit more tricky because we have to get the enum type from typeof enum
function fromValue<T>(o: T, value: string): { [P in keyof T]: T[P]  }[keyof T]{
    return  (o as any)[value]; // No type safety here unfrotunately
}

var value = fromValue(MyEnum, ""); //value will be of type MyEnum
```

Comment: Well... it's definitely not similar ;) works like a charm. I have question, what does the part `[keyof T]` stands for? Beside that i see that `keyof` was a... well key to solution. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

Beside perfect answer from Titan, here is a little tweak to work both ways regarding what type of value you wish to map from/to (string or number) and what unified result you wish (string or number):

```
enum MyEnum {
    'VAL_ONE' = 0,
    'VAL_TWO' = 1
}

function fromValuetoNumber<T>(o: T, value: string | number): {[P in keyof T]: T[P]} {
    if (typeof (value) === 'string') {
        return  (o as T)[value]; 
    } else if (typeof (value) === 'number') {
        return (o as T)[o[value]]
    }   
}

function fromValueToString<T>(o: T, value: string | number): {[P in keyof T]: T[P]} {
    if (typeof (value) === 'string') {
        return  (o as T)[o[value]]; 
    } else if (typeof (value) === 'number') {
        return (o as T)[value]
    }   
}

console.log(fromValuetoNumber(MyEnum, 'VAL_ONE'))
console.log(fromValuetoNumber(MyEnum, 0))

console.log(fromValueToString(MyEnum, 'VAL_ONE'))
console.log(fromValueToString(MyEnum, 0))
```

Only thing that still bothers me is fact, that if generic type  will be assigned, TypeScript goes crazy:

```
fromValueToString<MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'VAL_ONE')
```

Still, this is just an addition to original answer.

Comment: try fromValueToString<typeof MyEnum>(MyEnum, 'VAL_ONE')

Comment: Yeah, but this will not gain us much more type safety, since `typeof(AnyEnum)` is just an object, is that correct?

Comment: no it will not that is true, but what extra safety would you want maybe we can achieve it :)

Comment: Well I assume that validation of parameter `value` correctness is rather technical impossible (i.e. verifying that `string` in fact is `keyof` `MyEnum` or   number does have matching pair in enum set). It's just a bit confusing, that TypeScript don't treat enums as classes with dedicated type, rather than plain objects... Anyway, it's still cool :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `string literals` instead of enums?

I'm guessing that you are using the `enums` to avoid typos, and you want TypeScript to "catch" it for you. So if you use `string literals`, you are **type safe** and you will talk to the server in the same "language"

For example:

```
export type Sex = 'male' | 'female';
var sex: Sex = 'mela'; // Typo => ERROR from typescript
```

Comment: I'm afraid such easy transition is not possible, because we use them in one additional major use case, array indexation. In this case changing them to string literals (which in general i agree, would be beneficial from sake of simplicity) would make our life much harder

Answer (score 0):

Using `ts-enum-util` ([github](https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)), you can perform type-safe conversions between enum values and names (in either direction) with run-time validation. You can choose between variations of method that either throw an error or return a default value (undefined by default) if an invalid value is encountered at run time.

Example:

```
import {$enum} from "ts-enum-util";

enum MyEnum {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR = 1
}

function getMyEnum1(apiString: string): MyEnum {
    // throws informative error if "apiString" is not 
    // "FOO" or "BAR"
    return $enum(MyEnum).getValueOrThrow(apiString);
}

function getMyEnum2(apiString: string): MyEnum {
    // returns MyEnum.FOO if "apiString" is not 
    // "FOO" or "BAR"
    return $enum(MyEnum).getValueOrDefault(apiString, MyEnum.FOO);
}

function getMyEnum3(apiString: string): MyEnum | undefined {
    // returns undefined if "apiString" is not 
    // "FOO" or "BAR"
    return $enum(MyEnum).getValueOrDefault(apiString);
}

// type: ("FOO" | "BAR")
// value: "BAR"
const enumName = $enum(MyEnum).getKeyOrThrow(1);
```